# how to submit form when input type is image

Tags: jaunt-api

I am new for web scraping.For Scraping using amazing API Jaunt.I want to Filling-out form fields
and getting problem while submiting a form because used input type is image not an submit button.

**Sample Code:**

```
try {
            userAgent = new UserAgent();try {
            userAgent.visit("http://www.xxxx.com/section");          /
            } catch (ResponseException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JTicket.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
             Document doc = userAgent.doc;
             System.out.println(doc);
             Form form = userAgent.doc.getForm("<form name=browse>"); 
             form.setHidden("root", "10004");
             form.setHidden("category", "7");
             form.setHidden("rdc_select", "tw");
             form.submit("go");
```

**Background Code:**

```
    <form onsubmit="if (preProcessBrowse()) submitBrowseForm(this); return false;" id="ccs_form" name="browse" action="/browse">
  <input type="image" src="http://s1.ticketm.net/tm/en-us/img/sys/1000/blank.gif" title="Go" alt="Go" name="go" id="browse_go_button" class="go mgTop5 floatRight">
  <div class="clear">
  </div>
  <input type="hidden" value="tm_homeA_browse" name="tm_link">
  <input type="hidden" value="10004" id="root" name="root">
  <input type="hidden" value="7" id="category" name="category">
  <input type="hidden" value="mm" id="rdc_smonth" name="rdc_smonth">
  <input type="hidden" value="dd" id="rdc_sday" name="rdc_sday">
  <input type="hidden" value="yyyy" id="rdc_syear" name="rdc_syear">
  <input type="hidden" value="mm" id="rdc_emonth" name="rdc_emonth">
  <input type="hidden" value="dd" id="rdc_eday" name="rdc_eday">
  <input type="hidden" value="yyyy" id="rdc_eyear" name="rdc_eyear">
  <input type="hidden" value="tw" id="rdc_select" name="rdc_select">
  <input type="hidden" id="type" name="type" value="selected">
</form
```

**Image:**

[image]

Please help me, how to submit form using Jaunt.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post but it may help others
This might help you

http://jaunt-api.com/jaunt-tutorial.htm

Answer (score 0):

You remove the parameter and try form.submit() may work.